# pm2 logs error port:3000 please fix this error

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2

```
/Users/jake/.pm2/logs/main-error.log last 15 lines:
0|main     |     at listenInCluster (net.js:1356:12)
0|main     |     at Server.listen (net.js:1444:7)
0|main     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jake/Desktop/Nodejs-master/main.js:143:5)
0|main     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30)
0|main     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
0|main     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
0|main     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
0|main     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:32:23)
0|main     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30) {
0|main     |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|main     |   errno: -48,
0|main     |   syscall: 'listen',
0|main     |   address: '::',
0|main     |   port: 3000
0|main     | }
```

pm2 start main.js --watch   works  but when i try pm2 logs    i got above error 
anyone please help to fix this error thanks

Comment: The port 3000 is already in use... Maybe are you still running antoher program. Or maybe the instance of your app is still running somewhere, try to see where `ps aux|grep main.js` and kill it...

Answer (score 0):

EADDRINUSE means this port is already being used by some other application. Maybe a node is already running on this port.
First, run `sudo pkill -9 node` and use pm2. If this doesn't solve your problem, then ->

```
    kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
```